# Why are some pedestrian traffic lights covered in shades in London?

Tags: uk, london

I recently visited London and noticed some pedestrian traffic lights are covered weirdly so they're only visible from some angles.

[image: traffic lights in trafalgar square]

Looking it up in a search here didn't bring up any results.

Does anyone know why they're going through the trouble to do this?

Comment: Looking at this photo made me thinking of "grills", and after searching for "traffic light grill cover", I got more keywords like "louvred covers/blinds" and "slatted covers". Hopefully that could be useful for those who are interested in searching further...

Comment: Your question already contains the answer: it's so that they're only visible from some angles. The point being that the light controls one particular stream of people and they don't want other streams thinking "That light means me" when it doesn't.

Comment: @seadoggie01 It's the UK. There is no sun.

Comment: I've even seen lights with bulbous lenses or fresnel lenses in front to control which approach road sees the light.  Only seen where two roads meet at an angle well less than 90 degrees, perhaps as close as 20-30 degrees.

Comment: This is completely normal on traffic lights throughout the world.  There is no difference whatsoever in Europe, Asia, Americas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because traffic light technology is totally unrelated to Travel.  (The light-louvres mentioned are a commonplace on all traffic lights everywhere.)

Comment: They may be common in some parts of the world, they are surely not common all over the world and I feel this Q was closed without good reason.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We use these in the USA and that is the only place I have noticed them.

There are at least 2 general "shade" types, "visors" and "louvers".

1. Visors: Horizontal "shades" like the ones you posted are most likely
   to block the sun overpowering the light as this intersection
   probably faces roughly East/West. They also come in a few other shapes/forms.

   > The addition of a visor to a traffic-signal head that is in direct sunlight can improve visibility of the signal by providing
   >   additional contrast between the lens and the signal head. There are different types of visors including complete circle (or tunnel), partial (or cutaway) and angle visors. -[Source](https://safety.fhwa.dot.gov/intersection/conventional/signalized/rlr/rlr_toolbox/chap3.cfm)
2. Louvers: Louvers take many shapes but the most obvious is a vertical sort of
   "shade" like so. A Louver's purpose is to restrict the viewing angle of the signal. [image: louvers]

   > The purpose of a louver is to block the view of the signal from another approach. They are similar to angle visors but are better in
   >   limiting signal visibility to a narrow cone to the front of the
   >   signal. - [Source](https://safety.fhwa.dot.gov/intersection/conventional/signalized/rlr/rlr_toolbox/chap3.cfm)

It is also worth mentioning that *some* visor designs work well for the same purpose as Louvers, however Louvers don't generally do a very good job as Visors.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it contains trustworthy sources I can verify. I appreciate both other answers for their help.

Comment: Note that in the UK these would be called "Louvres" :)

Comment: I like that better @AakashM.

Answer (score 67):

You are most likely to find the green light with shades on the far side of a pedestrian crossing with a safety island (i.e. a two-part crossings, most often offset to each other), as illustrated below (the `o` are the traffic lights):

```
     Kerb
_____o------____ <- Shaded light
     .     .    >>> Traffic goes this way
     .     .
_____|=====o____ The safety island
   o=====|
   .     .      <<< Traffic goes this way
   .     .
___------o______ <- Shaded light
     Kerb
```

Due to road layout and light configurations, sometimes it is only safe to cross half of the road (up to the safety island). The shades ensure that you do not mistake the green light on the island as the signal to cross the entire road - you can only be sure that it is a green light (but not a broken light, which the general [highway code](https://www.highwaycodeuk.co.uk/rules-for-pedestrians-crossing-the-road.html) on crossing a uncontrolled crossing kicks in) once you are on the island.

Similar shades are installed on traffic lights for vehicles to reduce the risk of drivers running into an intersection thinking it is a green, when the light meant for the driver is showing red.

I do not have a written source to back up what I said above, though I was told this by my driving instructor when I learnt to drive in London a few years ago.

Comment: I believe that if the pedestrian light does not cover crossing teh whole road that the two crossings *must* be offset from each other. ie if the two crossings are aligned as in your ascii diagram that there shouldn't be separate lights covering each half. I do agree with the general comment that they are to prevent the wrong people from seeing them though.

Comment: @Chris A request for clarification - when you say 'offset' do you include cases where the two crossings are at a very slight angle to each other?

Comment: @Chris Actually, after more thinking I don't believe the two crossings must be offset. I spotted a few counterexamples on my way to work today, and shall do more research on this tonight to see whether it is not true or there exist sloppy implementations.

Comment: Rule 28 in https://www.highwaycodeuk.co.uk/rules-for-pedestrians-crossings.html explicitly says that if the crossings are not in line they are separate crossings. It does not say anywhere that inline crossings can be two separate crossings for light controlled and the fact that rule 28 exists implicitly suggests that inline crossings are a single crossing. That is also all the information I have on the technical rules for what makes a crossing offset.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind when you talk about crossings at an angle to each other - since crossings in my experience are always perpendicular to the road I'm wondering if you are considering two crossings on roads that meet next to the crossing in which case I would imagine that if they are separate roads they would be controlled separately (ie not considered the same crossing).

Comment: @Chris See the [pedestrian crossing at Pancras Road near Euston Road](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5301526,-0.1242262,3a,60y,88.68h,72.82t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sLSYxzyG7ix0Xv2hNEgTGtg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) for a inline pair of crossings, and [the junction between City Rd and East Rd](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5269336,-0.0879319,3a,60y,192.59h,69.95t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s9wm3LcGIRpQs2sGTrfeSMQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) for a slightly angled pair of crossings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83261/discussion-between-b-liu-and-chris).

Comment: If this is true, shouldn't the shades be vertical?

Comment: AFAIK the distinction between single and two-part crossings is not the geometry, but where there is a "refuge" (technical term) for pedestrians to wait between the two parts, *which is inaccessible to vehicles* - i.e. at a minimum it has "vehicles must pass on one side only" bollards at each end, and usually has a raised curb, guard railings, etc, as well. Any lights in the center of the road need to be protected from vehicles, which means that "central lights" and "a central refuge" go together in practice.

Answer (score 61):

These type of shades are not restricted to pedestrian traffic lights. They are widely used in the UK when there are many lights controlling different streams  of traffic around a junction.

Their purpose is to ensure that drivers (and pedestrians) can only see the lights that are relevant *to them* and avoid problems like traffic starting to move when *another* lane of traffic gets a green light.

The shutters are not always "horizontal" as in the OP's photograph. They may be "vertical," to prevent you seeing a light positioned *to the side* of the light that is relevant for you.

Comment: They're also known as snoots, as in, they're snooted. In photography we use snoots to control light from flash guns. As in your answer, it's to stop lanes of traffic for which the signal does not apply from seeing and reacting to the light.

Comment: The question only asks about the UK but these also exist in parts of the USA and I'm sure other areas of the world, all for the same purpose.

Comment: @SteveV. In the US (at least Seattle) I see traffic lights (but not pedestrian lights) with clear lenses on them instead of shutters/blinds and the lenses focus light so it's only visible in certain lanes and at certain distances from the light.

Comment: I believe this is the best and most concise answer. Very well explained and straight to the point.

Comment: This does not make sense at all for horizontal shutters like the one in the question.